# gitbash failing to run basic commands, mkdir, ls: "mkdir.exe has stopped working"

Tags: command-line, git-bash

I am trying to get to grips with using gitbash for basic command line operations.

According to [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457305/Basic-Git-Command-Line-Reference-for-Windows-Users) I should be able to, for example, type `ls` to display the contents of the current directory as a horizontal list.

This is what happens when I attempt to do that:

[image]

Same with mkdir:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this could be happening?